# LEFT JOIN with COUNT returns unexpected value

Tags: mysql, join, count, left-join, inner-join

I've two tables:

**post**:

```
id | body   | author | type | date
1  | hi!    | Igor   | 2    | 04-10
2  | hello! | Igor   | 1    | 04-10
3  | lol    | Igor   | 1    | 04-10
4  | good!  | Igor   | 3    | 04-10
5  | nice!  | Igor   | 2    | 04-10
6  | count  | Igor   | 3    | 04-10
7  | left   | Igor   | 3    | 04-10
8  | join   | Igor   | 4    | 04-10
```

**likes**:

```
id | author | post_id
1  | Igor   | 2
2  | Igor   | 5
3  | Igor   | 6
4  | Igor   | 8
```

And I want to do a query that returns the number of posts made by Igor with type 2, 3 or 4 and number of likes made by Igor too, so, I did:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.type = 2 OR p.type = 3 OR p.type = 4) AS numberPhotos, COUNT(DISTINCT l.id) AS numberLikes
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN likes l
ON p.author = l.author
WHERE p.author = 'Igor'
```

And the expected output is:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["numberPhotos"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["numberLikes"]=>
    string(2) "4"
  }
}
```

But the output is:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["numberPhotos"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["numberLikes"]=>
    string(2) "4" (numberLikes output is right)
  }
}
```

So, how to do this?

Comment: You want the number of likes by post? Or sum of eveything?

Comment: @llouk no. I want the number of likes in general made by Igor. The `numberLikes` output is correct, the problem is with `numberPhotos` output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `p.type = 2 OR p.type = 3 OR p.type = 4` evaluates to either `1` or `0`, so there are only 2 possible distinct counts.

To fix the issue, you can use a `case` statement:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT case when p.type in (2,3,4) then p.id end)
```

Comment: With your answer, the numberPhotos output is 3 and not 6

Comment: @Igor I made a correction. The last part should be `then p.id` instead of `then p.type`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post p WHERE p.type = 2 OR p.type = 3 OR p.type = 4  AND p.author = 'Igor') AS numberPhotos, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes l WHERE l.auhtor = 'Igor') AS numberLikes`

Answer (score 1):

How about this.(A bit of modification from your query sql).

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.type = 2) + COUNT(DISTINCT p.type = 3) + COUNT(DISTINCT p.type = 4) AS numberPhotos,       COUNT(DISTINCT l.id) AS numberLikes
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN likes l
ON p.author = l.author
WHERE p.author = 'Igor'
```